# Regex to match number in a string enclosed within brackets or Parenthesis

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have a dataset where each line contains a number that is enclosed within a set of parenthesis or brackets. e.g.

```
Jim Bob Smith [1975] 
Joe Bob Public (1955)
```

What I'm having problems with is creating a regex expression that will match the number (without the brackets or parenthesis) that will work under both conditions.

I've tried

```
(?<=\[).+?(?=\]) and
(?<=\().+?(?=\))
```

So I need help finding a way to combine the two.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following .NET regex:

```
(?:(\()|\[)(.*?)(?(1)\)|])
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%28%5C%28%29%7C%5C%5B%29%28.*%3F%29%28%3F%281%29%5C%29%7C%5D%29&i=Jim%20Bob%20Smith%20%5B1975%5D%20%0D%0AJoe%20Bob%20Public%20%281955%29)

**Details**

- `(?:(\()|\[)` - a [non-capturing group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#noncapturing_group) that matches and captures into Group 1 a `(` char, else just matches a `[` char
- `(.*?)`  - Group 2: any 0 or more chars other than a newline char, as few as possible (instead of `.*?`, you might want to use `\d+` there to match 1 or more digits, or `\d{4}` to match just four digits exactly, or even `(?:20|19)\d{2}` to match a year in the 20th and 21st c.)
- `(?(1)\)|])` - a [conditional construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/alternation-constructs-in-regular-expressions#conditional-matching-based-on-a-valid-captured-group): if Group 1 was matched, a `)` is matched, else, a `]` char.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
.*?[[(](\d{4})[])]
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/4RpAuS/5)

1. `.*?` - non greedy any char
2. `[[(]` for either opening quote
3. `(\d{4})` - creates the 4 digit capture group you want.
4. `[])]` for either closing quote

Comment: Note it [will also match](https://regex101.com/r/4RpAuS/2) `(1235]` and `[1234)` like strings.